# C# winForm Basics Combobox

Tags: c#, winforms, combobox

hey all, i've built a ComboBox that gets manually items like this:

```
var newitem = new { fullname =c.Company+" "+ c.FirstName + " " + c.LastName,
                    custId = c.CustomerID };

c_dropCustomers.Items.Add(newitem);
```

later on on combo Selection event, i would want to get out the custId (The Value) only
but i dont know how to reach it.

SOS :)

Comment: see this sample : [Loop through combo box items ](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/Forums/ShowMessages.aspx?ThreadID=43850)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

asuming c# 4.0:

```
dynamic item = c_dropCustomers.SelectedItem;
dynamic customerID = item.custId;
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to actually define a class, so that you can cast to it later. You can't cast to an anonymous class (AFAIK).

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly:

```
var item = c_dropCustomers.SelectedItem;
var custId = item.custId;
```

**EDIT:**
(C# 3.5)

If it really is an anonymous type you'll need to do something like this:

```
        ComboBox cb = new ComboBox();
        cb.Items.Add(new { fullname = "Company" + " " + "First Name" + " " + "Last Name", custId = 44 });

        cb.SelectedIndex = 0;

        var item = cb.SelectedItem;
        var custId = item.GetType().GetProperty("custId").GetValue(item, System.Reflection.BindingFlags.GetProperty, null, null, null);
```